# How to create Windows 10 provisioning package with working installation of Visual Studio 2015 Community?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2015, usmt

I'm messing around with provisioning packages for Windows 10 using USMT and new `/apps` option to ScanState to [minimize amount of software to manually reinstall](https://superuser.com/q/1076185/106115). However I noticed that [in spite of the promises to get all the files outside of OS into a package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt170656(v=vs.85).aspx), I face "expired prerelease software" akin to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31725192/673826) upon reinstalling Windows from Recovery Drive, going through OOBE, and starting VS. Same happens if I go straight to Audit mode. So I have to reinstall VS. Is there a way to properly package it into PPKG?

I tried to run plain dumb

```
scanstate /apps /ppkg c:\recovery\customizations\apps.ppkg
```

followed by creating Recovery Drive and reinstalling Windows from it.

Comment: I think this is a question which should be better migrated to serverfault.com because the question is enterprise/business related

Comment: I'm a home/hobby user in this context. I just want custom Recovery Drive for Windows 10. Otherwise referenced related question also has to go.

Comment: ok, check this topic: http://superuser.com/q/1076185/174557

Comment: And? It is my reply in there;) and I mention this particular problem with this application. Everything else works for me.